# Compare value of rows SUM in SQL query

Tags: ms-access

I would like to select the rows where OutgoingInvoice.TPP field not equals the SUM of Products.IncomingSUM where the OutgoingInvoice.ID = Products.OutgoingInvoice

I wrote this SQL query:

> SELECT j.* FROM OutgoingInvoice AS j
> WHERE (((j.TPP)<>(select sum (jj.IncomingSUM)
> from Products as jj
> where jj.OutgoingInvoice = j.ID )
> ));

It do not shows any rows, but there are some. What do I wrong?

Comment: I found the main problem: SELECT j.* FROM OutgoingInvoice AS j WHERE (((j.TPP)<>(select sum (jj.IncomingSUM) from Products as jj WHERE  j.ID= jj.OutgoingInvoice ))); change the order after the second WHERE.

Comment: But still not list the rows where OutgoingInvoice.TPP = 0 and the related IncoingSUM <>0. Why? How can I include? Maybe a JOIN?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `WHERE NOT EXISTS` instead of `<>`

```
 SELECT j.* FROM OutgoingInvoice AS j 
 WHERE NOT EXISTS(((j.TPP) = (select sum (jj.IncomingSUM) from Products as jj where jj.OutgoingInvoice = j.ID ) ));
```